# Making a Chronogram from an newick tree in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I have a custom tree of extinct taxa in the form of an newick file. I want to use R to create a figure of said tree with the each node having the matching period of time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `ape` to load the newick tree a plot it.
For example:

```
## Loading the tree
my_tree <- ape::read.tree("path_to_your_tree")
## Plotting the tree
plot(my_tree)
## Adding a scale bar
ape::axisPhylo()
```

For more fancy plots, I suggest you have an in depth look at the functions in [`ape`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/ape.pdf), [`ggtree`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggtree/versions/1.4.11) or [`strap`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/strap/strap.pdf) (for nice geological time scales).

Comment: Is there an elegant way to import the dates of each taxon's appearance and extinction dates to the newick tree?

Comment: I don't know what you mean referring to "elegant" but a newick tree typically only contains branch lengths information. You probably want to import the dates using another file (maybe a `.csv` or something alike).